# Recuperar id capturado com JS no modal

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel

Tenho um `button` que chama um modal para confirmação de exclusão, este esta em uma tabela, cada linha um `button` pra excluir o cadastro daquela linha

Porém da maneira que está ele sempre exclui o primeiro item da lista

```
<button type="button" id="btn-modal" cidadao-id="{{$cidadao->id}}" class="btn-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default">{{$cidadao->id}}</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-default">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmação</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Deseja realmente excluir o cadastro?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            <form id="formdelete" class="form-vertical" method="POST" action="{{ action('CidadaoController@destroy', $cidadao->id)}}">
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')                                               
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{$cidadao->id}}</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Consegui capturar o id correto com JS:

```
$('.btn-modal').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('cidadao-id');
    console.log(id);
    //document.formdelete.action = "{{ action('CidadaoController@destroy', id)}}";
})
```

Tentei substituir o action para utilizar o id que capturei, porém não funcionou

Como poderia fazer para deletar o cadastro do id capturado?

Comment: Testei da forma como está e funcionou https://jsfiddle.net/ph3rx4bc/1/

Comment: Eu só recomendo alterar cidadao-id para data-cidadao-id e utilizar no lugar de attr data https://jsfiddle.net/ph3rx4bc/4/

Comment: @WictorChaves obrigado vou fazer isso, mas quanto a recuperar o id no modal não saberia me dizer como?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui

Ficou assim o form:

```
<form class="formdelete" name="formdelete" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')                                               
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Excluir</button>
</form>
```

E assim no JS:

```
$('.btn-modal').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data('cidadao-id');
    //console.log(id); 
    $(".formdelete").attr('action', ("cidadaos/"+id));
})
```